# How many bits are needed for signed int and behavior at bitwise shift to the left of a number that is a limit of his type

Tags: c++, binary

**Question № 1:**
*how many bits are needed for `signed int`?*

I know that `int` requires 4 bytes or 32 bits (it depends on architecture, but usually it is so), and i also know that there one bit for sign of a number.

2147483647 is only 31 bits, not 32. So, one bit for a sign?
4294967295 is 32 bits. There no one bit for a sign (because `unsigned`).

Why specify that `signed int` have 32 bits, when in fact its value can has only 31? Why not specify that one bit is given for a sign?

**Question № 2:** 
*behavior at bitwise shift to the left of a number that is a limit of his type?*

What will be the value of a and b?

```
int a = 2147483647;
a <<= 1;

unsigned int b = 4294967295;
b <<= 1;
```

How does the value change when the number reached the limit of its type?
Somewhere write that the behavior will be like a № 1, and somewhere write, that the behavior will be like a № 2.

```
1111111111111111111111111111111 << 1 = 1111111111111111111111111111110; // № 1.
1111111111111111111111111111111 << 1 = 10; // № 2.
```

Comment: One question per question please.

Comment: @Scheff "Just try it" is not a good approach here. Signed integer overflow as probably happens in Q2 is undefined behavior, which is really difficult to draw conclusions from.

Comment: You are supposing that `int` is 32 bits, but that's not required. `int` is allowed to be as small as 16 bits. See [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) if you need specific sized integers.

Comment: Typical platforms (and some parts of the standard I think) require [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) which does not use a sign bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant rule here is [[expr.shift]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift#2):

> The value of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. If `E1` has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. Otherwise, if `E1` has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So, assuming you're on a platform with 32-bit 2s complement `int`, this:

```
int a = 2147483647;
a <<= 1;
```

`a` has a signed type and `2147483647 x 2` is representable in `unsigned int`, so we get `0xfffffffe` as an `int`, which is `-2`.

And this:

```
unsigned int b = 4294967295;
b <<= 1;
```

is just modular arithmetic. We start with `0xffffffff`. Shift by one would give you `0x1fffffffe`, but then modulo 2<sup>32</sup> and get back `0xfffffffe`, which is `4294967294`.

Both are well-defined behavior. However, note that `a << 2` would be undefined behavior because `2147483647 x 4` is not representable in `unsigned int`.

Comment: "Undefined behavior" – what this approximately mean about? Random number, crash or something?

Comment: By my reading *" if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the resulting value"* + [*If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#pre-4) makes `a <<= 1` UB, not `-2`. What am I missing?

Comment: @Barry I got it. Can you say something about the first question?

Comment: @nwp Hmmmmm. I think you might be right. My interpretation wouldn't make much sense in retrospect?

Comment: It makes sense with a certain reading of "converted to the result type". The question is if a conversion includes a truncation and hence the value is in range or not. I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: @nwp The text changed in C++14. Check out the [bitwise shift section](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic). Now I'm really confused.

Comment: hmm, I think the result is implementation defined. Because converting UINT_MAX-1 to `int` is such. So the result is not necessarily -2. You must consult the compiler manual.

Comment: @Barry so the purpose was to allow it to be used in a constant expression. It wasn't the purpose to define a value for it. "If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type; otherwise, the value is implementation-defined."